# Topshelf WhenContinued not working

Tags: c#, windows-services, topshelf

Topshelf is not working when I add whencontinued in the configuration. It is working fine with start and stop methods. I do not have any code in continue method that would block it from running ( simple console.writeline )

```
  HostFactory.Run(x =>
           {
               x.SetDescription("Data Service - POC");
               x.SetDisplayName("Data Service");
               x.SetServiceName("DataService");
               x.EnablePauseAndContinue();
               x.Service<SampleService>(s =>
               {
                   s.ConstructUsing(() => new SampleService());                    
                   s.WhenStarted(v => v.Start());                   
                   s.WhenStopped(v => v.Stop());
                  // s.WhenContinued(v => v.Continue());

               });
               x.RunAsLocalSystem();

           });
```

what am I missing ?

It is compiling fine. It is not calling any of my methods . I see console flash and disappear. I cant even read what is on that console. If I comment out the line s.WhenContinued(v => v.Continue()); it is working fine

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Doesn't compile, throws an exception, something else?

Comment: It is compiling fine.  It is not calling any of my methods . I see console flash and disappear. I cant even read what is on that console. If I comment out the line s.WhenContinued(v => v.Continue()); it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires pause to be configured as well. once I added pause method to configuration it started working.

```
HostFactory.Run(x =>
       {
           x.SetDescription("Data Service - POC");
           x.SetDisplayName("Data Service");
           x.SetServiceName("DataService");
           x.EnablePauseAndContinue();
           x.Service<SampleService>(s =>
           {
               s.ConstructUsing(() => new SampleService());                    
               s.WhenStarted(v => v.Start());                   
               s.WhenStopped(v => v.Stop());
               s.WhenPaused(v => v.AnotherPause());
               s.WhenContinued(v => v.Continue());

           });
           x.RunAsLocalSystem();

       });
```